# Having issues with python IDLE invalid syntax

Tags: python

**Error:-**

[image]

**Code:-**

```
def main():
    
    # Input
    place = input("Will we go to north carolina?")
    if (place == "Yes"):
        print ("The drive will take all most a full day.")
    else:
        print ("I do not know how long the drive wil last.")
   
main()
```

It is saying invalid syntax and highlighting the main in red

Comment: Can you try entering the function first, then press enter twice so that you'll see ">>>" on the screen again, then call the main function.

Answer (score 1):

You should run this multiline code in the script mode by going to New -> File

If you want to use this only, click enter twice after the function to get the prompt back